# Getting information out of a set<MyClass> mySet

Tags: c++, class, static, set

So I've got

```
set<MyClass> mySet;
```

and in MyClass I have a static int to count the number of compares that happen. I'm trying to get that information out of it but I can't figure out how.

This is what I've tried:

```
set<MyClass>::iterator it = mySet.begin();
int count = it->getCompareCount();
```

and

```
int count = mySet.begin()->getCompareCount();
```

Neither of those work (Yes I know the are essentially the same exact thing) but I can get that information out of something that is indexed like a std::list or std::vector

Example:

```
vector<MyClass> myVector;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    myVector.push_back(MyClass(i,"Some Name", i*2);
}
int count = myVector.at(2).getCompareCount(); //which by default is going to be 0 as no compares have taken place
```

Can anybody help me? netbeans says "error: passing ‘const MyClass’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int MyClass::getCompareCount()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]" when I do what I said I tried up above.

***EDITS***

Declaration of getCompareCount():

```
int MyClass::getCompareCount()
{
    return compareCount;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `getCompareCount()`?

Comment: added that for you jeffamaphone

Comment: Are you perhaps calling `int count = mySet.begin()->getCompareCount();` from inside a `const` function? If so, make `getCompareCount()` a `const` method (it should be anyway).

Comment: I'm not calling `int count = mySet.begin()->getCompareCount();` from inside a const function. and I made the getCompareCount const as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element in std::set is not mutable after it is inserted into the set. When you dereference an iterator (as in it->), it returns a const reference of the object you put into the set. On the other hand, your definition of getCompareCount() is a non-const instance function meaning it can only be called on non-const instance of the class. Define the function as the following should solve your problem.

```
int MyClass::getCompareCount() const
{
    return compareCount;
}
```

By the way, since compareCount is a static int, you might want to define the function as static as well so that you can call it using the class instead of having to get an instance to call it.

```
static int MyClass::getCompareCount()
{
    return compareCount;
}
//To Call it
MyClass::getCompareCount()
```

Comment: Thanks I couldn't get the first one to work but making the function static worked.